# How to add wordpress plugins in along with my standalone theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, custom-field

I am developing my own custom WordPress theme but in my custom theme i am using some of plugins. Actually i am adding some custom field plugin to customize the text on my theme. My problem is that when i install my theme in another WordPress website setup the errors occurs because plugins are not added. I want to know that how can i add or attach others plugins with my theme so that when i need to install my theme to another WordPress website setup these plugins should installed automatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) library to let the user know about required and recommended plguins that your theme depends on.

Automatically installing plugins is not a better choice instead let the users know that `X plugin` should be installed and activated in order for the theme to work properly.

If your theme requires a plugin without which it gives error then make sure to add checks for functions like so:

```
if(function_exists('xplugin_function')){
   //code
}
```